# FileZilla cannot open folders for installed package in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, filezilla

I installed LLVM and its components on Ubuntu 18.04. After installation, I wanted to see the installation files to verify them.

The files are located in separate folders in /usr/bin and identical folders in /usr/lib/llvm-8/bin, but when I click on any of the folders, Filezilla responds:

```
Error:  Directory /usr/lib/llvm-8/bin/clang: no such file or directory

Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Whether I navigate to subfolders in /usr/bin or /usr/lib/llvm-8/bin I get the same error message.

I kept the compete installation dialog from Putty for each of the components when I installed it and there were no error messages.

What does this mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like whatever username you are using to connect doesn't have [permission](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/understanding-linux-file-permissions/) to read the contents of those folders. This might be due to those folders being owned by root and having very limited permissions or it might be due to the server being configured to [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) or "[jail](https://serverfault.com/questions/24706/what-does-ftp-jailing-mean-and-what-features-does-a-server-os-require-in-order)" the user to some subdirectory.

You generally shouldn't use FTP to connect to a server. The data is not encrypted in transit.

Consider connecting via [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) and learning a few terminal commands:

```sh
ls -al /usr/lib/llvm-8/bin
```

Comment: Thanks, @S. Imp - my Filezilla is set up for SFTP - SSH File Transfer Protocol, so it's (supposedly) as safe as terminal SSH.  Anyway, I used Putty (SSH) with your directory listing command, and I can see all the files now, including the ones I wanted to verify.  I'm really surprised that SFTP was not able to do this because it's never failed me before.  Thanks very much for your reply.

Comment: @RTC222 I seem to recall that "[sftp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFTP)" can mean more than one thing and doesn't always refer to "SSH File Transfer Protocol." I used to rely very heavily on FTP programs like FileZilla but have eliminated them from my workflow by a) switching my workstation to ubuntu so I can develop locally instead of constantly uploading to the server, b) learning better command line skills like scp and rsync, and c) using git to manage my source code and deploy changes to my server.

Comment: Thanks for the additional points.  rsync is on my to-do list, coming up soon.  Among other things, rsync is used by Postgres for database sync.  I do develop locally, but sometimes I need to upload, and I too am wary of the security of FTP, even though FileZilla claims it's SSH File Transfer Protocol.